# How to print the next line from a file, if current line contains a string?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write something to print certain lines from a file. Let's say the file looks like this:

```
name = 1
name = a
name = 2
name = b
name = 3
extra = 1
name = c
name = 4
extra = 1
name = d
```

So normally I could do `if line startswith(name)` and print them all out, but let's say I need only the lines that start with "name", that come after lines that start with "extra". But I can't figure out how to print something like `line + 1`. How do I print the next line based off of what the previous line says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your input processing loop, keep a copy of the current input line and name it something like `previous_line`.  Then on the next iteration you'll have access to both the current input line and the previous input line.

```
previous_line = ''
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('name') and previous_line.startswith('extra'):
        print line
    # keep a copy of this line for the next loop
    previous_line = line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a boolean flag and print only if the flag is set. Something like:

```
print_next_line = False
for line in f_in:
    if print_next_line:
        print(line)
        print_next_line = False
    else:
        print_next_line = line.startswith()
```